# How to Overcome "Must not with Sudo" error in setting up Github Actions config on VPS

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, vps, github-actions

I am attempting to setup Github actions runner on my Ubuntu VPS and on step 3 where I have to set up the config.sh file, I get the error as : `Must not run with Sudo` and the process fails there. My root account is password protected though and I do not understand what is the issue here. But any what I am looking for is how to get through this problem. I am not actually deploying a serious app, this is all just for practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're running the commands as the root user. Either create a new user using `sudo newuser {username}` or run the command `export {AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"}` i recommend option 1 but both work just fine.

Comment: As I said, this was for learning purposes and so I tried both of the suggestions on different servers. They all seem to work just fine. Thanks

Comment: for me exporting the variable only worked this way: `export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"`